# How to link a brand new Xcode project to an existing iOS app on App Store?

Tags: ios, apple-developer, app-distribution

I created a new project using Xcode to refactor my existing app on the App Store, and I need to be able to continue releasing new updates on the same app on the app store

I added the apple developer account that is used to upload the existing app to Xcode and I chose it in the signing & capabilities

also I set the bundle ID in the new project to be as same as the exisitng app , but I get the warning of "Failed to register bundle identifier" and that is obviously because the bundleID has already been used before for the already exising app on the App Store.

How to properly link the Xcode project to my existing app?

Comment: It sounds like you have not selected the same developer account/team that owns the existing app and it is trying to register a new bundle id.